# Amazon EC2 - hacked by magic_404

Tags: amazon-ec2

My Amazon EC2 instance has been hacked, the index.php file on the attached volume was replaced to the attached code, and the screen display the attached image

I solved it quickly by replacing the index.php to the original one

My question is: how can I prevent similar attack in the future? i.e. what security step should I take to secure my: srv, volume, login, firewall, console, etc.

FYI this hack was a result of a Trojan in guiminer

[image]

```
<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">

<META NAME="ROBOTS" CONTENT="INDEX, NOFOLLOW">







<!DOCTYPE html><html>
<link rel="SHORTCUT ICON" href="https://s-media-cache-ak0.pinimg.com/736x/96/32/00/963200f696520af71661e4587f48c95d.jpg">
<head>
<title>HACKED BY MAGIC_404</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=gb2312">
<style type="text/css">*{margin:0;padding:0;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-ms-box-sizing:border-box;-o-box-sizing:border-box;box-sizing:border-box}body,html{margin:0;padding:0;font:16px/1.4 Lato,sans-serif;color:#fefeff;-webkit-font-smoothing:antialiased;font-smoothing:antialiased;font-family:Comic Sans MS}body{background:#080510;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none}h1{font:2.75em Cinzel,serif;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:.35em;text-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(254,254,255,.85)}h2{font:1.45em Cinzel,serif;font-weight:400;letter-spacing:.5em;text-shadow:0 0 25px rgba(254,254,255,.85);text-transform:lowercase}[class^=letter]{-webkit-transition:opacity 3s ease;-moz-transition:opacity 3s ease;transition:opacity 3s ease}.letter-0{transition-delay:.2s}.letter-1{transition-delay:.4s}.letter-2{transition-delay:.6s}.letter-3{transition-delay:.8s}.letter-4{transition-delay:1s}.letter-5{transition-delay:1.2s}.letter-6{transition-delay:1.4s}.letter-7{transition-delay:1.6s}.letter-8{transition-delay:1.8s}.letter-9{transition-delay:2s}.letter-10{transition-delay:2.2s}.letter-11{transition-delay:2.4s}.letter-12{transition-delay:2.6s}.letter-13{transition-delay:2.8s}.letter-14{transition-delay:3s}h1,h2{visibility:hidden;-webkit-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);-moz-transform:translate3d(0,0,0);transform:translate3d(0,0,0)}h1.transition-in,h2.transition-in{visibility:visible}h1 [class^=letter],h2 [class^=letter]{opacity:0}h1.transition-in [class^=letter],h2.transition-in [class^=letter]{opacity:1}#container{display:table;position:absolute;z-index:20;width:100%;height:100%;text-align:center;cursor:none}#container>div{display:table-cell;vertical-align:middle}#container p{position:absolute;width:100%;left:0;bottom:25px;font-size:.8em;letter-spacing:.1em;font-weight:300;color:#76747a;-webkit-font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased;font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased}#container p strong{color:#b3abc5}#container p span{font-size:.75em;padding:0 2px}#canvas{position:absolute;z-index:10;top:0;left:0;width:100%;height:100%;cursor:none}#stats{position:absolute;z-index:10;left:10px;top:10px}.dg.ac{z-index:100!important}.STYLE4{color:#FFF}
</style>
</head>
<body oncontextmenu='return false;' onkeydown='return false;' onmousedown='return false;'>
<body ondragstart="window.event.returnValue=false" oncontextmenu="window.event.returnValue=false" onselectstart="event.returnValue=false">
<div id="container">
<div><br><br><br><br>
</object>
<h1 id="h1">HACKED BY MAGIC_404</h1>
</br>
<h2 id="h2">T.I SNIPER</h2>
<h3 id="h3"><br></h3>
<h4 id="h4">Sorry admin your security is less secure, increase the security of your website and do not forget to increase faith also </h4>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<p class="style14" align="center"> <font color="#ffffff" face="courier new" size="3"> Family :</font><marquee scrolldelay="20" scrollamount="2" direction="left" behavior="scroll" width="50%">
<font color="#ff0000" face="Tahoma" size="3">HUMAN_CRAZY99|/Hookers|Wak-Lay|36015| Ustazah |/RzCyber48|MickeyMouse|DewaSEX|Mr.Q|MR.bla|C4pt.danzm! |P.E.K.K.404|Z0NK_|Mr_V1ru5 |Member Show-off Zone Sniper Cyber

</font></marquee><br></p><p align="center">
</div>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<script>
var Stats=function(){var e=Date.now(),t=e,i=0,n=1/0,r=0,s=0,o=1/0,a=0,l=0,h=0,c=document.createElement("div");c.id="stats",c.addEventListener("mousedown",function(e){e.preventDefault(),v(++h%2)},!1),c.style.cssText="width:80px;opacity:0.9;cursor:pointer";var u=document.createElement("div");u.id="fps",u.style.cssText="padding:0 0 3px 3px;text-align:left;background-color:#002",c.appendChild(u);var d=document.createElement("div");d.id="fpsText",d.style.cssText="color:#0ff;font-family:Comic Sans MS;font-size:9px;font-weight:bold;line-height:15px",d.innerHTML="FPS",u.appendChild(d);var p=document.createElement("div");for(p.id="fpsGraph",p.style.cssText="position:relative;width:74px;height:30px;background-color:#0ff",u.appendChild(p);74>p.children.length;){var f=document.createElement("span");f.style.cssText="width:1px;height:30px;float:left;background-color:#113",p.appendChild(f)}var m=document.createElement("div");m.id="ms",m.style.cssText="padding:0 0 3px 3px;text-align:left;background-color:#020;display:none",c.appendChild(m);var g=document.createElement("div");g.id="msText",g.style.cssText="color:#0f0;font-family:Comic Sans MS;font-size:9px;font-weight:bold;line-height:15px",g.innerHTML="MS",m.appendChild(g);var y=document.createElement("div");for(y.id="msGraph",y.style.cssText="position:relative;width:74px;height:30px;background-color:#0f0",m.appendChild(y);74>y.children.length;){var f=document.createElement("span");f.style.cssText="width:1px;height:30px;float:left;background-color:#131",y.appendChild(f)}var v=function(e){switch(h=e){case 0:u.style.display="block",m.style.display="none";break;case 1:u.style.display="none",m.style.display="block"}},b=function(e,t){var i=e.appendChild(e.firstChild);i.style.height=t+"px"};return{REVISION:11,domElement:c,setMode:v,begin:function(){e=Date.now()},end:function(){var h=Date.now();return i=h-e,n=Math.min(n,i),r=Math.max(r,i),g.textContent=i+" MS ("+n+"-"+r+")",b(y,Math.min(30,30-30*(i/200))),l++,h>t+1e3&&(s=Math.round(1e3*l/(h-t)),o=Math.min(o,s),a=Math.max(a,s),d.textContent=s+" FPS ("+o+"-"+a+")",b(p,Math.min(30,30-30*(s/100))),t=h,l=0),h},update:function(){e=this.end()}}};
</script>
<script>
;(function(window) {
var ctx,
hue,
logo,
form,
buffer,
target = {},
tendrils = [],
settings = {};
settings.debug = true;
settings.friction = 0.5;
settings.trails = 20;
settings.size = 50;
settings.dampening = 0.25;
settings.tension = 0.98;
Math.TWO_PI = Math.PI * 2;
// ========================================================================================
// Oscillator
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Oscillator(options) {
this.init(options || {});
}
Oscillator.prototype = (function() {
var value = 0;
return {
init: function(options) {
this.phase = options.phase || 0;
this.offset = options.offset || 0;
this.frequency = options.frequency || 0.001;
this.amplitude = options.amplitude || 1;
},
update: function() {
this.phase += this.frequency;
value = this.offset + Math.sin(this.phase) * this.amplitude;
return value;
},
value: function() {
return value;
}
};
})();
// ========================================================================================
// Tendril
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function Tendril(options) {
this.init(options || {});
}
Tendril.prototype = (function() {
function Node() {
this.x = 0;
this.y = 0;
this.vy = 0;
this.vx = 0;
}
return {
init: function(options) {
this.spring = options.spring + (Math.random() * 0.1) - 0.05;
this.friction = settings.friction + (Math.random() * 0.01) - 0.005;
this.nodes = [];
for(var i = 0, node; i < settings.size; i++) {
node = new Node();
node.x = target.x;
node.y = target.y;
this.nodes.push(node);
}
},
update: function() {
var spring = this.spring,
node = this.nodes[0];
node.vx += (target.x - node.x) * spring;
node.vy += (target.y - node.y) * spring;
for(var prev, i = 0, n = this.nodes.length; i < n; i++) {
node = this.nodes[i];
if(i > 0) {
prev = this.nodes[i - 1];
node.vx += (prev.x - node.x) * spring;
node.vy += (prev.y - node.y) * spring;
node.vx += prev.vx * settings.dampening;
node.vy += prev.vy * settings.dampening;
}
node.vx *= this.friction;
node.vy *= this.friction;
node.x += node.vx;
node.y += node.vy;
spring *= settings.tension;
}
},
draw: function() {
var x = this.nodes[0].x,
y = this.nodes[0].y,
a, b;
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(x, y);
for(var i = 1, n = this.nodes.length - 2; i < n; i++) {
a = this.nodes[i];
b = this.nodes[i + 1];
x = (a.x + b.x) * 0.5;
y = (a.y + b.y) * 0.5;
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(a.x, a.y, x, y);
}
a = this.nodes[i];
b = this.nodes[i + 1];
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(a.x, a.y, b.x, b.y);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
}
};
})();
// ----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
function init(event) {
document.removeEventListener('mousemove', init);
document.removeEventListener('touchstart', init);
document.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemove);
document.addEventListener('touchmove', mousemove);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', touchstart);
mousemove(event);
reset();
loop();
}
function reset() {
tendrils = [];
for(var i = 0; i < settings.trails; i++) {
tendrils.push(new Tendril({
spring: 0.45 + 0.025 * (i / settings.trails)
}));
}
}
function loop() {
if(!ctx.running) return;
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(8,5,16,0.4)';
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
ctx.strokeStyle = 'hsla(' + Math.round(hue.update()) + ',90%,50%,0.25)';
ctx.lineWidth = 1;
if(ctx.frame % 60 == 0) {
console.log(hue.update(), Math.round(hue.update()), hue.phase, hue.offset, hue.frequency, hue.amplitude);
}
for(var i = 0, tendril; i < settings.trails; i++) {
tendril = tendrils[i];
tendril.update();
tendril.draw();
}
ctx.frame++;
ctx.stats.update();
requestAnimFrame(loop);
}
function resize() {
ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
}
function start() {
if(!ctx.running) {
ctx.running = true;
loop();
}
}
function stop() {
ctx.running = false;
}
function mousemove(event) {
if(event.touches) {
target.x = event.touches[0].pageX;
target.y = event.touches[0].pageY;
} else {
target.x = event.clientX
target.y = event.clientY;
}
event.preventDefault();
}
function touchstart(event) {
if(event.touches.length == 1) {
target.x = event.touches[0].pageX;
target.y = event.touches[0].pageY;
}
}
function keyup(event) {
switch(event.keyCode) {
case 32:
save();
break;
default:
// console.log(event.keyCode);
}
}
function letters(id) {
var el = document.getElementById(id),
letters = el.innerHTML.replace('&amp;', '&').split(''),
heading = '';
for(var i = 0, n = letters.length, letter; i < n; i++) {
letter = letters[i].replace('&', '&amp');
heading += letter.trim() ? '<span class="letter-' + i + '">' + letter + '</span>' : '&nbsp;';
}
el.innerHTML = heading;
setTimeout(function() {
el.className = 'transition-in';
}, (Math.random() * 500) + 500);
}
function save() {
if(!buffer) {
buffer = document.createElement('canvas');
buffer.width = screen.availWidth;
buffer.height = screen.availHeight;
buffer.ctx = buffer.getContext('2d');
form = document.createElement('form');
form.method = 'post';
form.input = document.createElement('input');
form.input.type = 'hidden';
form.input.name = 'data';
form.appendChild(form.input);
document.body.appendChild(form);
}
buffer.ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(8,5,16)';
buffer.ctx.fillRect(0, 0, buffer.width, buffer.height);
buffer.ctx.drawImage(canvas,
Math.round(buffer.width / 2 - canvas.width / 2),
Math.round(buffer.height / 2 - canvas.height / 2)
);
buffer.ctx.drawImage(logo,
Math.round(buffer.width / 2 - logo.width / 4),
Math.round(buffer.height / 2 - logo.height / 4),
logo.width / 2,
logo.height / 2
);
window.open(buffer.toDataURL(), 'wallpaper', 'top=0,left=0,width=' + buffer.width + ',height=' + buffer.height);
// form.input.value = buffer.toDataURL().substr(22);
// form.submit();
}
window.requestAnimFrame = (function() {
return window.requestAnimationFrame || window.webkitRequestAnimationFrame || window.mozRequestAnimationFrame || function(fn) { window.setTimeout(fn, 1000 / 60) };
})();
window.onload = function() {
ctx = document.getElementById('canvas').getContext('2d');
ctx.stats = new Stats();
ctx.running = true;
ctx.frame = 1;
logo = new Image();
logo.src = 'http://labs.nikrowell.com/lightsandmotion/ultraviolet/images/logo.png';
hue = new Oscillator({
phase: Math.random() * Math.TWO_PI,
amplitude: 85,
frequency: 0.0015,
offset: 285
});
letters('h1');
letters('h2');
document.addEventListener('mousemove', init);
document.addEventListener('touchstart', init);
document.body.addEventListener('orientationchange', resize);
window.addEventListener('resize', resize);
window.addEventListener('keyup', keyup);
window.addEventListener('focus', start);
window.addEventListener('blur', stop);
resize();
if(window.DEBUG) {
var gui = new dat.GUI();
// gui.add(settings, 'debug');
settings.gui.add(settings, 'trails', 1, 30).onChange(reset);
settings.gui.add(settings, 'size', 25, 75).onFinishChange(reset);
settings.gui.add(settings, 'friction', 0.45, 0.55).onFinishChange(reset);
settings.gui.add(settings, 'dampening', 0.01, 0.4).onFinishChange(reset);
settings.gui.add(settings, 'tension', 0.95, 0.999).onFinishChange(reset);
document.body.appendChild(ctx.stats.domElement);
}
};
})(window);
</script>
<embed src="https://www.youtube.com/v/Vx0kE5kBNxk&autoplay=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" wmode="transparent" width="1" height="1"></embed>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You **cannot** trust your instance or anything on it now, even if you have "fixed" the first hint of intrusion.

Things you should do **immediately**:

- Stop that instance and install a new one from scratch.  The intruder could have changed system files, left themselves a backdoor, or done who knows what.
- If you have any passwords, SSL certificates with keys, or API keys stored on the instance, those are compromised, and must be changed immediately.

Without knowing how you set up the original instance, it's impossible to say exactly how it was hacked, but you should ALWAYS do the following:

- Make sure you keep your application versions (web server, php, sshd) up-to-date with the latest security patches.
- Make sure you're following security best practices for your web server
- Use a php security scanner regularly.
- Do not open any ports to the world.  If you're serving HTTP on a public website, it's generally better to put that behind an ELB.
- Disable password logins for sshd.  Use keys only.

Comment: Backup all the logs before you nuke the old instance so you can figure out how it was hacked in the first place.

Comment: The hack was done by a trojan installed on my local PC with a bitcoin miner/wallet - Bitcoin Wallet: http://bitcoin.org/en/choose-your-wallet
GUI Miner: https://bitcointalk.org/?topic=3878.0

Answer (score 0):

I found the following https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HXbDNPh0aTc

This is a prestashop hack caused by simpleslideshow, I removed this module completely.